# I am having an error Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Quotation'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having an error in my component 
Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Quotation'.
I am getting error on this line
for (let i = 0; i < data.*length*; i++)

component

```
getQuotationDocumentNumber(): void {
    this.quotationservice.getQuotationDocumentNumber(this.objQuotationDocument.QuotationFinancialYearId, this.objQuotationDocument.CustomerId).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.quotationdocument = Array(); 
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          this.quotationdocument.push({ Id: data[i].Id, SerialNumber: data[i].SerialNumber, FinancialYear: data[i].FinancialYear.ShortTitle });
        }
      });
  }
```

Model

```
import { Customer } from './customer';
import { Quotation } from './Quotation';

export interface QuotationDocument
{
    CustomerId: number;   
    Customer: Customer;
    CustomerName: string;
    QuotationId: number;   
    QuotationFinancialYearId: number;
    Quotation: Quotation;
    QuotationSerialNumber: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Observable returned by your `getQuotationDocumentNumber()` is emitting a `Quotation` type, which does not have a `length` property.

EDIT: modify your service method to return the type you're looking for. Alternatively, if it's a specific field on the `Quotation` type, don't forget to extract it.